# .htaccess subfolders redirect with making other subfolder available?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following folders structure

```
/folder1/main/
/folder1/administrator
/folder2/
```

I want to write a .htaccess file that redirects the clients from the root to `/folder1/main/` but let `/folder1/administrator` and `/folder2/` available if requested directly?

Any help please?

Comment: To be clear, you want all requests that do not otherwise exist to redirect to `folder1/main/`?

Comment: yes exactly all requests that do not exist will be redirected to folder1/main

Comment: i am novice in .htaccess so if you can write the whole code please :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common pattern. The general solution is to put in before the `RewriteRule` a couple of conditions "don't do this if the request filename is a directory" and ditto for file. The conditions are:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```